# Extracting two or three smaller functions from main() to find errors more easily

Tags: python

I would like to extract shorter functions from the larger main function to make this more readable and easier to find errors without removing functionality

I was thinking of splitting it down the middle like shown with "def calc_mean():. However an issue is that data amongst other things is not defined in this function. How should I change these so the original program still works despite being divided into 2?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to call `main()` at the end of the file?

Comment: I have "if __name__ == '__main__':
            main()
at the end of the program and it doesn't help much. The big issue is really that I don't know how to accurately extract and define functions from the original main function still.

Answer (score 1):

It is a never ending loop.
`user_input` calls `main`, then `main` calls `user_input`, then `user_input` calls `main` and so on.

FIX 1

Remove `filename = input(user_input())` from main function and pass `filename` as an argument from `user_input` . In this case whole script should first call `user_input` function.

FIX 2

Remove `filename = input(user_input())` with `filename = user_input()` adjust `user_input` function so it would only ask for user input and then return that input. In this case script should first call `main` function.

Also, in the bottom of the script it should be

```
if __name__ == '__main__': # not `main`
     call_some_function()
```

Update

```
def user_input(): # adjust this if you need
     filename = input()
     return filename

def read_data(filename):
    data = dict()              
    with open(filename, 'r') as h:
        for line in h:
            four_vals = line.split(',')
            batch = four_vals[0]
            if not batch in data:
                data[batch] = []
            data[batch] += [(float(four_vals[1]), float(four_vals[2]), float(four_vals[3]))]
    return data


def calc_mean(sample):
    if len(sample) == 0:
        return
    n = 0
    x_sum = 0
    for (x, y, val) in sample:
        if x**2 + y**2 <= 1:
            x_sum += val
            n += 1
    average = x_sum / n
    return average


def main():
    '''
    This is the main body of the program.
    '''
    filename = user_input()
    data = read_data(file_name)
    for batch, sample in data.items():
        average = calc_mean(sample)
        if average is not None:
            print(f"{batch}\t{average}")
        else:
             print(f"{batch}\t{No data}")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , I used fix2 and it worked. While I have you here, do you spot any potential functions that could be extracted from the original main() apart from the user_input? It's for a project where I will have to make it easier to read and to make it simpler to find errors. Thanks!

Comment: 1. function to read data and prepare it. 2. function to do stuff with the data.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too basically splitting the main() down the middle. However I'm not sure how I can use variables from one function in another? I'm struggling of getting it to carry over to the "new" function. I'll provide an edit

Comment: I provided a small edit, I didnt get far, would you mind helping me a bit further?